# What is single word for omit the details?

Tags: word-request

I am writing a manual like below:

> 1. do A.
> 2. do B.
> 3. do C (omit the details).

step 3 is already mentioned in another document, the reader of this manual already knows the details.
so I want to indicate step 3 is only the abbreviation. What is the best word put into `( ? )`

Comment: Depending on the exact context, I would either include it *anyway* (there's no guarantee that somebody knows the other details, and repetition in technical manuals in some cases isn't bad), or say something like *For more information, see …*, and provide a hyperlinked heading to the other section or chapter, or a hyperlinked title of the other document. I wouldn't recommend using a single word in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the order of preference:

Choice 1:

Instead of "(omit the details)", write "Refer to section 3.4.1".  That is, give them a "hyperlink" to the information. This seems like the best option.

Choice 2:

If you strongly believe the reader already knows the answer (which might be an incorrect assumption) then just say "do C", and nothing more.

Choice 3:

Write "The details have been omitted" which could be abbreviated as only two words - "details omitted".